# How to easily approximate irrational/transcendental numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Question:** Do we have an easy way to find the approximate solutions to irrational numbers, such as $\sqrt{19}$ and transcendental numbers such as $e^{\sqrt5}$

The question arose when I read online that an "easy" way to approximate irrational numbers, for example, $\sqrt{5}$, by finding two numbers whose squares "encapsulate" the square root. ($2^2$ and $3^2$ in this case), and by common sense, we can find the approximate forms.

Personally, I believe this to be too much work. So I'm wondering if we have a nice "trick" to be able to *accurately* find the decimal approximations of simple irrational numbers such as $\sqrt{5}$, and if we have a method for finding *transcendental* numbers such as $e^{\text{some irrational number}}$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The easiest (and very powerful) method is to use the continued fractions. We get arbitary good rational approximations for every number.

Comment: @Peter Continued fractions? Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Just google it, but I give an example. The continued fraction of $\pi$ is $3,7,15,1,292,\cdots$. So, the number $3+\frac{1}{7+\frac{1}{15+\frac{1}{1}}}=\frac{355}{113}$ is an approximation of $\pi$. It is very good because $292$ is "large"

Comment: @Peter Sure, but how would you generate the seemingly random string of numbers $3,7,15,1,292\ldots$

Comment: Assume the given number is positive. The first entry is the integer part of the number. Subtract it and take the reciprocal. Then, the integer part is the next entry and so on. For more details, look at wikipedia, for example.